# PHP Classes not found with crontab

Tags: php, class, cron

I have a PHP script that reads email, saves the attachments, read the saved csv files and load a DB with the content of the csv files.
I use the Jamesiarmes\PhpEws library to connect to my Exchange Server and all is working perfectly.
As I need to do it every day, I use crontab to run the PHP script every day at ten o'clock.

```
00 10 * * * /usr/bin/php /home/web/update/format-recent-report.php > /home/web/log/readmail.log 2> /home/web/log/readmail.err
```

The problem arises when Crontab tries to run the script. The readmail.err file contains the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Client' not found in
>   /home/web/update/exchange_config.php on line 8

Here it is the `exchange_config.php`:

```
<?php 
use \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Client;
$host = 'xxx.xxxx.it';
$username = 'yyyyy';
$password = 'zzzzzz';
$version = Client::VERSION_2010;
?>
```

Afetr getting the error, I go to the directory where the script is located and try to run the script manually with:

```
php format-recent-report.php > log
```

and the script works correctly. Why this difference between crontab and manual ?

I don't post the content of the PHP script because it is very long, but I can say that it starts with:

```
include '../vendor/autoload.php';
include 'exchange_config.php';
```

it stops at the very beginning.

Comment: Your script is probably not running from the directory that you think it is, you can use `getcwd` to check that. Using absolute paths would solve that.

Comment: your paths are not absolute, as such are dependent onthe current working directory. Obviously the file you're trying to include are not being included (that's the problem for you to fix).

Answer (score 3):

If you start script with cron always use full path of file.

Add to every path in your script `dirname(__FILE__)` and add `/` if necessary.

Comment: @AD7six That might solve the specific issue, but you should always use absolute paths to avoid any issues that might arise from traversing through the directories with `..` and such. Using absolute paths would have avoided the issue from the start.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois actually I find it better to do as OP says, because if you change environments it will still work. If you use absolute paths, you'd have to change all occurrences.